# Friedman test for small sample single arm trial?

Tags: nonparametric, friedman-test

I am looking at a single arm clinical study with a small sample size (n=14), where each patient was assessed 5 times (weeks 1-5, once a week). I have constructed linear models to see if the change-over-time is significant and then looked at the QQ-plots to assess normality of the residuals. They sort of look normally distributed, but with such a small sample its hard to say for sure.

To convince myself of the results, I want to run an alternative analysis that does not require normality. I wonder if the Friedman test is appropriate in this case? What makes me uncertain is that using [this formulation of the test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/friedman.htm), I wonder if it is appropriate to think of the 5 measurement timepoints as different 'treatments' within the block (where 'block' corresponds to a patient)? What bothers me is that you can administer 5 treatments independently, but timepoints are not independent from each other, making me uncertain.

I ran the Friedman test just to see what happens and qualitatively the results are the same as for linear model i built first. Nonetheless, I would be grateful if you could chip in whether Friedman is appropriate for this situation. If not, what alternative tests you would suggest?

Comment: "To convince myself of the results, I want to run an alternative analysis that does not require normality." .... As a general principle, different test statistics for different hypotheses operating under different assumptions won't necessarily result in "consistent" conclusions even if nothing whatever is wrong. It might help you spot some interesting feature of the data (e.g. mean and median difference not being very similar), but that's not going to help you; among other things such post hoc filtering likely interferes with the properties of your test (like significance levels).